# Curl won't submit form. Why not?

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to run CURL from the command line, to submit a form.  The form is created from  php script (see below), that can be accessed via the URL:

http://london.scripts.mit.edu/z.php

I've tried numerous CURL commands from linux, and none of them work.  For example:

curl -X POST -F "name=test" https://london.scripts.mit.edu/z.php

I realize that there is some obvious flaw that I'm overlooking, because this feature is so well documented.   But it doesn't work for me.  Thanks. - Mark

```
<?php
print "<!DOCTYPE html>";
print "<html><body>";
print "<p>Enter name:</p>";
print "<form action=\"./request_account.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"form\">\n";
print "<input type = \"text\" name = \"name\" id = \"name\"><br />\n";
print "<input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\" id = \"submit\">\n";
print "</form></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request
Try --data instead of -f

Comment: Also documented in the curl book: [-d vs -F](https://ec.haxx.se/http-postvspost.html)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried the different options on the command line without any luck.  I've modified the script, so that it will print out $_POST, to show it's properly receiving the POST data, but that the submit button simply isn't being pressed.  Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that curl won't directly execute the action script specified by the html form command.  There are workarounds on the web, but I'm going to simply not use a separate action script.